# Cosa significa "battuta" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> – Senti tu, – gli disse uno, – patti chiari: se vuoi essere con noi, le **battute** le fai con noi e ci insegni tutti i passi che sai. 
>         – E ci lasci entrare nel frutteto di tuo padre! – disse un altro.  – A me una volta mi ci hanno sparato col sale!

Si tratta di frasi pronunciate da ragazzi che, per necessità, rubano la frutta dagli orti. Sono dirette a Cosimo, il protagonista del romanzo, figlio del Barone di Rondò.

La mia domanda è sul senso del vocabolo  "battuta" in questo passaggio. Tra le diverse accezioni di questo termine che ho trovato nei dizionari, non sono sicura a quale corrisponda l'occorrenza nel testo.
Significa una frase spiritosa? Vuol dire invece un'azione organizzata per rubare la frutta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo contesto, il significato di *battuta* è collegato al punto 6a della [voce del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/battuta/). Significa, dunque, un'azione organizzata per "andare a caccia" di frutta.